# Labels and Pins with Tikzlibrary Graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I want to draw a simple block diagram with boxes, additions, multiplications, splits with pgf 3.0.0.

I am quite content with the result so far, but I can not pin (with arrow) or label the nodes in the graph.

Also I would like to have a little circle at every end and beginning, like "in o-->|something|--o out" and a filled dot indicating branching nodes.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mult}{
\tikz[x=3mm,y=3mm] \draw[red] (0,0) -- (1,1) (0,1) -- (1,0);
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every pin edge/.style={<-},
    pin distance=4,
    vh path/.style = {to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
    block/.style = {
        rectangle, minimum size=6mm,draw},
    mul/.style = {draw,circle,inner sep=0},
    shape = coordinate
    ]
\graph [grow right sep, branch down=2, simple,fresh nodes] {
    / -> "$\int$"[block] -- / -> [vh path]
        {[nodes={yshift=1cm}]
        "\mult"[mul,pin=above:$\frac{1}{2}$] -- "$\eta |\cdot|^2$"[block] -- /,
        "\mult"[mul,pin=above:$\frac{1}{2}$] -- something[block] -- / % does not work as intended
        };
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is a picture of the MWE:
[image: see above]

Alternatives that I know are using a matrix, relative positioning and manual placing. However, I like the graph approach and I would like to get it to work. Further suggestions are always welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that in the options to the `tikzpicture` environment you have used `shape=coordinate`. This sets the default shape to a coordinate which means when a node is drawn and the shape is not *explicitly* given, a coordinate will be used and the text ignored.

One solution is to use `every pin/.style={shape=rectangle}` in the `tikzpicture` keys:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mult}{\tikz[x=3mm,y=3mm]\draw[red] (0,0) -- (1,1) (0,1) -- (1,0);}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[ %every pin edge/.style={arrows=<-},
  pin distance=4,
  vh path/.style={to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
  block/.style={rectangle, minimum size=6mm,draw},
  mul/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=0},
  shape=coordinate,
  every pin/.style={shape=rectangle}
]
\graph [grow right sep, branch down=2, simple,fresh nodes] {
  / -> "$\int$"[block] -- / -> [vh path]
  {[nodes={yshift=1cm}]
    "\mult"[mul,pin=above:$\frac{1}{2}$] -- "$\eta |\cdot|^2$"[block] -- /,
    "\mult"[mul,pin=above:$\frac{1}{2}$] -- something[block] -- /
  };
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so far. Actually, I would like to have pin arrows. However, if I add "every pin edge/.style={<-}" to the options of the tikzpicture environment, no arrows are shown. Additionally, what is your preferred way (xshift works of course) to have both endings at the same x-level.

Comment: @apfel Inside the graph there may be some interaction with the graph drawing keys (I guess). Explicitly setting the arrows using `every pin edge/.style={arrows=<-}` appears to work. Currently I cannot think of easy way of aligning the ends except by manual adjustment.